# How to use webbrowsr control with Httpwebrequest?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, httpwebrequest, linkedin-api

I am using webbrowser control , and i get list of all the url of all the profiles from the search result.

After this is there any way that i use httpwebrequest to get the data from the urls?

I wanted to use the Linked in search profile api but that is very confusing.
Also i tried using httpwebrequest but it takes me to the linkedin login page.

I was thinking of any way that as i signed in to linkedin using the webbrowser control maybe using that information of webbrowser and adding with my request to pretend to be logged in .

Any ideas? Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HttpWebRequest sent you to the login page, because there isn´t the cookie with the validation.
So, you'll can connect using WebBrowser control and get the cookie, then put the cookie in the webrequest

```
        webBrowser.Navigate(someUrl);

        ...

        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        foreach (string cookie in webBrowser.Document.Cookie.Split(';'))
        {
            string name = cookie.Split('=')[0];
            string value = cookie.Substring(name.Length + 1);
            string path = "/";
            string domain = "yourdomain.com";
            cookies.Add(new Cookie(name.Trim(), value.Trim(), path, domain));
        }


        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.CookieContainer = cookies;
        ...
```

Comment: And for a Google Session cookie? NID=59=pmQMpgkKO7k-3CVa35WjgvZHYPGZm3KVFILmQ [etc...] I guess there's more than one standard.